# Omit values with typescript when both are the same in the object

Tags: typescript, lodash

I would like to achieve result of only unique values in `object2` and tell also to typescript to omit those keys from `T`:

```
const diff = <T extends {}>(object1: T, object2: T) => {
  const diffValues = {}
  for (const key in object1) {
    if (object1[key] !== object2[key]) {
      diffValues[key] = object2[key]
    }
  }
  return diffValues;
}
```

so I could see it like this:

```
const res = diff({ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }) // return type { a: number }
const res = diff({ a: 1, b: 'value' }, { a: 1, b: 'value2' }) // return type { b: string }
```

I tried with lodash `omit` but no success. Is there some trick to tell typescript how to infere that return type more precisely than only `Partial<T>`?

Comment: ① What does this have to do with lodash? Just a failed attempt at a solution?  Does the question depend on lodash in some way? ② Is the use case really just passing object literals to `diff` where the compiler knows the actual literal property values like `1` and `2` as opposed to `number`?  I sort of doubt that will happen (since you could just do the diff yourself beforehand, I'd think, if that's the situation).  Like, what would you want `diff(x, y)`'s type to be if the type of `x` and `y` are both `{a: number, b: string}`?  How could it be any more precise than `{a?: number, b?: string}`?

Comment: `valuesKey` is just key of object - it should be `key` in this case I changed the example code.Both object1 and object2 are the same but first will be default one and second will be after update. Lets imagine I have form that need defaultValues, and after submit they will change depends on user choice. I would achieve (if possible) that I will omit fields that values are the same. 

The question is if I can tell typescript to return `T` but using for example`Omit<T, ???>` and ??? are the fields that did not changed in compare of two objects.

Comment: How would you expect *TypeScript* to know what fields will be the same/different *at runtime*?  You know that TypeScript will be long gone by the time any users interact with JavaScript, right?  Could you show a more typical use case?  Again, with object literals like `{a: 1}`, the compiler knows that the property value of `a` is `1` (as opposed to just `number`) and can compare it to `{a: 2}`.  But if all the compiler knows is that both inputs are `{a: number}`, how could it *possibly* give you anything more precise than `{a?: number}`? Can you articulate a scenario where this makes sense?